# Gridview ItemTemplate ControlStyle-Width ignores right-side padding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a GridView as follows and wish to make the TextBoxes fill the columns properly. At the moment, setting Controlstyle-Width="100%" doesn't work as expected; there is padding top, left and bottom, but it ignores right side padding and expands to the edge of the column.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvTimesheets" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvTimesheet_RowDataBound" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Position">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPositions" runat="server" Width="200/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" HeaderStyle-Width="100%" ControlStyle-Width="100%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Enabled="true" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The reason I have the description `HeaderStyle-Width` set to 100% is because I want it to fill the remaining space once the control is fully populated, this seems to work perfectly fine.

I have tried using `box-sizing`, `ControlStyle-Width`, `ItemStyle-Width` but nothing seems to keep the right-side padding. Any suggestions? I would prefer to stick with .Net and avoid jQuery, etc.

Comment: remove HeaderStyle-Width="100%" ControlStyle-Width="100%" and simply use ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"...i think it will help for you..

Comment: HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" just changes the text alignment in the header. ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" moves the text box aligned with the right of the column, but doesn't fill the column. As stated, I want HeaderStyle-Width to be 100% so that it fills remaining space. I tried having ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" along with ItemStyle-Width="100%" and also tried switching to ControlStyle-Width="100%", issue remains though...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Use Width="100%" property with  tag in the ItemTemplate and then, if required, set alignments as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply